# sharepoint 2013 error Page not found 404

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

i installed new sp 2003 standard trial on w2k8r2sp1 and my domain is on 2003 server with exchange 2003 on seperate system, sp machine is a client of DC, at start up it was working fine, the default page was accessible but when i tried to change authentication method, from NTLM to kerberos now PAGE NOT FOUND error,

i deleted the default web application and re installed but the error is same , i tried to fix it from IIS but i think i messed up , i can open central admin but default port 80 page is not working . some time i get connection close with full information of iis 7.5 etc. 
i can see only this on page below :::

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Date: Sat, 23 Mar 2013 17:17:57 GMT
Connection: close

i tried it from localhost, system name , ip from the network but no luck .

any idea ? its my development sp but i am worried if i go for production i might happend again ..

your help is appreciated :)

Malik

Comment: did you created a site collection on that web application? as you are accessing from local machine, did you disabled LoopBack check??

Comment: hi C.Marius thanks for answering ,

i just created site collection and guess what its working like charm but still i cant access root site 80 and even i created 8080 new site that is not accessible but site collection does. 

when i try to click from site collection to newsfeed or sites i get same error or some time 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 

i just disabled Loopback check and restarted but its the same .. 

any idea ?

Comment: hi again, i guess my default site 80 and site collections have issues , now i cant access site collection as well, 
i cant access http://w2k8r2sp13 and http://w2k8r2sp13/sites/malik as well ... 
but another site http://w2k8r2sp13:8088 doesnt work but when i created new site collection under this works find http://w2k8r2sp13:8088/sites/chase..........

Comment: http://w2k8r2sp13/sites/malik/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Community Home.aspx

403 FORBIDDEN

http://w2k8r2sp13/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx

403 FORBIDDEN

Answer (score 3):

Reason :

I found that the reason is during the web application creation process IIS is reset and by default. It allows the "Shutdown time limit" which by default is 90 seconds. Sometimes this might not be enough. And hence it forcibly shuts down in 90 seconds.

Resolution Steps (Worked for me):

Go to application pool of Central Administration.

Right click on it and go to Advanced Settings

In the Process Model section, increase the shutdown time limit to 200 for example.

It is a good idea to restart IIS now.